# de Sitter Spacetime: Static patch vs Global coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, de-sitter-spacetime

Two well-known coordinate charts on the dS spacetime are the global coordinates and the static patch coordinates. In the global coordinates, the D-dimensional dS metric takes the following form
$$ ds^2 = -dt_g^2 + l^2 \cosh^2(t_g/l) d\Omega_{D-1}^2$$ where $t_g$ is the global time and $l$ is the radius of the dS space. Clearly, the metric components are time-dependent and hence non-static. In fact, this metric shares the form with the FRW metric which describes an expanding universe in the future.

With the help of the static patch coordinates, we can write the dS metric in the form
$$ds^2 = -(1-r^2/l^2)dt_s^2 + \frac{1}{1-r^2/l^2}dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega^2_{D-2}$$ where $t_s$ is the time in the static patch. Clearly, this is a static metric with a timelike Killing vector $\partial_{t_s}$. My question is, how can the same manifold express both an FRW expanding universe and a static Schwarzschild-like spacetime just because we are using different coordinates? For example, we know that the energy is conserved in a static spacetime whereas it is not conserved in an FRW metric. Wouldn't this give rise to contradicting statements on the same manifold? Clearly I am missing something here, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties you mention are coordinate-dependent but actually they are *(conformal-)Killing vector* dependent. The complete dS spacetime has several such vector fields so that all those properties may co-exist. Furthermore, since they refer to *intrinsic geometric structures*, they may have a physical meaning.

The global coordinates you mention actually define intrinsic geometric global structures proper of solutions of FLRW spacetimes:

(a) a global foliation made of spacelike 3D conformally-isometric manifolds with intrisic positive constant curvature, whose metric is $d\Omega_{D-1}$ up to a scale factor,

(b) a *conformal Killing time* globally defined $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}:=\ell \cosh(t_g/\ell) \frac{\partial}{\partial t_g}\:.$$  With respect to that notion  of conformal time $\eta$ only massless fields (photons) admit conserved (conformal) energy described in terms of a density in the rest spaces of the foliation.

However, referring to subregions of the spacetime, further (infinitely many) geometric structures take place. In those regions, further conservation laws are admitted. In every static region, the corresponding Killing vector $\partial_{t_s}$ permits a local conservation law referred to its flow and densities assigned on the orthogonal notion of rest space.

The situation is quite similar to that of Minkowski spacetime. There, we have a pair of timelike Killing vectors (actually infinitely many such pairs). One is the standard global *Minkowski Killing vector time* $\partial_t$, the other is the so-called *Rindler Killing vector* $\partial_\tau$ which is timelike in the Killing wedges $|x|> t$ giving rise to further conservation laws of corresponding notions of energy.

Coming back to dS spacetime and its physics, the crucial physical fact that makes  relevant $\partial_{t_g}$ shows up  when assuming that this spacetime is a solution of the Einstein equations for a suitable type of gravitational sources.

According to  FLRW models, the integral curves of  $\partial_{t_g}$ are the *worldlines of the sources of gravitation for the Einstein equations* (the stories of the clusters of galaxies in general, but in the case of the pure dS spacetime, the four-velocity field of the  perfect fluid made of  dark energy).

Furthermore, the above-mentioned 3-surfaces orthogonal to those curves define the common rest spaces where the *expansion of the universe* is measured and where the background cosmic radiation appears to be *isotropic* with the measured temperature $\simeq 3 K$ (in the pure  dS spacetime there is no radiation however).

In this cosmological model the static regions have no direct meaning, because the integral lines of the static time are not the worldlines of the source of the gravitation.

Comment: +1 Valter, but isn't the question really _is the universe expanding or not?_

Comment: (Victor?) The fact that it is expanding is an "accepted experimental fact" obviously assuming several hypotheses as is the standard in physics (facts are however interpreted by a theory).

Comment: I'm happy that it's expanding Valter. (sorry I called you Victor!) Heck, even if we had no experimental evidence for it, I'd be saying space just _has_ to expand. For the life of me,  I don't know why Einstein didn't. Of course, he did in the end, with the Einstein–de Sitter universe in 1932. I like this by the way: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08029

Comment: (no problem, I like Victor as a name!) Thanks for the ref

Comment: @ValterMoretti So, to check if I understood correctly, the static patch does not cover the whole deSitter manifold, and hence in the part it covers, a timelike Killing vector is allowed, whereas the global coordinate covers the entire dS manifold (which only allows conformal timelike Killing vectors). Also, is it possible to extend the static patch to cover the entire manifold like we do for maximally extended Schwarzschild solution?

Comment: The static patch cannot be extended since the Killing vector, which is static in the patch, becomes lightlike on the boundary of the patch and spacelike outside the patch and it is defined in the whole dS spacetime. However you can act on the rigid stucture with every isometry of dS producing different but isometric structures (infinitely many similar Killing structures). All this is similar to what happens in Minkowski spacetime where you can act on every Minkowski frame with isomteries also moving the associated static Rindler wedges.

Comment: It is however **different** of what happens in the complete Schwarzschild-Kruskal spacetime where the Killing structure is instead **invariant** under the action of the isometries.

Comment: @ValterMoretti I am not sure I get your comment. The Killing vectors are defined by the isometries. So what do you mean exactly when you say that the Killing structure is invariant under isometries in one case, and not in the other. More specifically what do you mean by Killing structure?

Comment: For Killing structure I meant above the integral submanifolds of the Killing field defining the static time. In the Kruskal spacetime this structure, the bifurcate horizon in particular, is invariant under the action of all the isometries of the spacetime. The analogous structure in the Minkowski spacetime is generated by the boost vector and, e.g.,  it is not invariant under standard spacetime translations nor spatial rotations.

Answer (score 1):

The de Sitter spacetime possesses *scale invariance.* That is to say, the only matter content allowed in a consistent theory of dS spacetime has conformal symmetry, and therefore does not feel the expansion of spacetime. In this sense, the dilution characteristic of FLRW spacetimes is not felt by the matter in a consistent dS cosmology, and hence it possesses a time-like killing vector.

In theories where the universe has matter content, the universe is only *approximately* de Sitter, as we observe in the slightly negative CMB power spectrum tilt. This slight tilt represents the slightly broken scale invariance of de Sitter during inflation: the size of the horizon, $l$, in your metric, is a function of time in any realistic theory, and therefore these new coordinates do not possess a timelike killing vector.